# Select one of each matching results from group last record from date

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have multiple customers that are a part of a group designated by a group id.

I would like to retrieve 1 record from a related table for each of the matching group members (last record before a certain date).

Currently I query for a list of group members then for each member i run another query to retrieve last record from a date.

I would like to do this with **one** query since i can pull up the associated table records using group id - however this returns **all** the records associated to group (bad).

If i use `first` or `default` i only get results for **first** group found. 
I want **1** record from **each** group member.

My Code (returns all associated records of group members):

```
  List<Record> rs = (from x in db.Records where (x.Customer.Group == udcg && x.CloseDate < date && x.CloseDate < earlyDate) orderby x.CloseDate descending select x).ToList();
```

But i just want **one** from each instead of **all**.

Code I use now:

```
var custs = (from x in db.Customers where (x.group == udcg) select new { x.CustomerID }).ToList();
    expected = custs.Count();
    foreach (var cust in custs)
    {
      Record br = (from x in db.Records where (x.Customer.CustomerID == cust.CustomerID && x.CloseDate < date && x.CloseDate < earlyDate)) orderby x.CloseDate descending select x).FirstOrDefault();
      if (br != null)
        {
           total = (double)br.BillTotal;
           cnt++;        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work

```
db.Customers
    .Where(c => c.group == udcg)
    .Select(c => db.Records
            .Where(r => r.Customer.CustomerID == c.CustomerID)
            .Where(r => r.CloseDate < date)
            .Where(r => r.CloseDate > date.AddMonths(-2))
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.CloseDate)
            .FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(r => r != null)
```

It is translated into one sql query. That means it uses one roundtrip to the server. That could be quite a big difference in performace when compared to the foreach loop. If you look at the generated sql, it would be something like

```
SELECT some columns
FROM Customers
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) some columns
    FROM Records
    WHERE some conditions
    ORDER BY CloseData DESC
    )
```

In terms of performace of the query itself, I would not expect problems here, sql server should not have problems optimizing this form (compared to other ways you could write this query).

Comment: In terms of efficiency. Do the inline functions do basically the same thing i was doing separately or is it much more optimized? or Pushed to the SQL server to process?

Comment: if the answer is correct please give credit by marking the answer (tick) as `answered`

Comment: @GerakORE: While one can rarely be certain about how SQL Server will perform with its queries, this will most likely perform better than what you did before. Rather than loading all of the objects across the network from SQL Server to memory, you are allowing the database engine to do the kind of querying it's been optimized to do well, and return only the results you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, evaluate records list.

```
DateTime certain_date = new DateTime(2018, 11, 1);

List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

var query = records.GroupBy(x => x.Customer.Group).Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, LastRecordBeforeCertainDate = g.Where(l => l.CloseDate < certain_date).OrderByDescending(l => l.CloseDate).FirstOrDefault() });
```